# Training N classifiers for N labels vs one classifier with N labels

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, multi-class, tensorflow, multitask-learning

I have a classification problem which is multi-label with N labels. I would like to know which method would be the better choice? Training N classifiers (1 for each label) or a single classifier which use K-hot encoding. I'm using a neural network for this with a softmax at the last layer. (Is there any chance that the softmax would cause a problem?) I'm using tensorflow for the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It mostly depends on your labels. Training one classifier with N labels (= multitask) makes more sense when labels are related. But one cannot predict in advance with 100% certainty whether multitask will outperform single task (= training N classifiers for N labels)

---

This paper studied the question:  Caruana, R. (1997). Multitask learning: A knowledge-based source of inductive bias. Machine Learning, 28:41--75. doi:10.1023/A:1007379606734 ; http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1007379606734 ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1023/A:1007379606734

Single task:

[image]

Multi task:

[image]